# How to solve the Access Denied

Tags: c#

I'm try to access the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository.
But it gives me the error message: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository' is denied.

```
var path = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

foreach (var file in files)
{
     //Get file information
}
```

How to solve this problem using code?

Comment: You can't solve it using code only, it's a system issue. Run your program as administrator

Comment: Try to run it as administrator i guess

Comment: Or grant read privilege for this folder to the user (you) that executes the application.